# SELECT all rows WHERE id = id and another column = another column with that ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union

Hi everyone I am trying to

```
 SELECT * rows WHERE id = (for example) 123.
```

Also, I want to select the column `favorite_number` from row 123 and select all WHERE id = `favorite_number` of id = 123. How can I do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id = :id) OR (id = :id AND get favorite_number from that row and search for it as ID);
```

Example: SELECT all rows with ID = 123. Also, if that row's column `favorite_number` IS NOT NULL AND does not = 0, select `favorite_number` (in this example, let's say the number is 456) and then search the same table: WHERE id = 456.

**How can I do this all in one search query?** I hope this is clear enough, thanks!

Comment: "I hope this is clear enough, thanks!" No it's not clear see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selfjoin;

```
SELECT * -- You should always explicitly select the columns rather than *
FROM    users us
LEFT JOIN users uf
         ON uf.Id = us.favorite_number
WHERE us.id = 123
```

Obviously you can change to an inner join if required and add more where conditions (or join conditions).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From Users Where Id = 123 Or Id in
(Select favorite_number From Users Where Id = 123 And favorite_number Is Not Null And favorite_number <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for both the condition on the same rows  but for different column 
in this way you should add  an AND condtion extending where

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id = :id
AND favorite_number = :id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want 1 or 2 rows and you can do it with UNION:

```
select * from tablename
where id = 123
union all
select * from tablename
where id = (
  select favorite_number from tablename where id = 123
)
```

In case `favorite_number` is `null` or `0` then nothing will be fetched by the 2nd query.